# \index{} within \pagenote{} does not work, when using \emph{} in \index{}

Tags: indexing, pagenote

The following MWE shows 4 index entries, with 2 different wordings, and 2 in ordinary text, and 2 in `\pagenote`. 2 are normalfont, the other 2 are `emphasized`. The result should be 2 indexes, 1 with normalfont and the other `emphasized`. But the result are 3 indexes: 1 normalfont, `2 emphasized`.

How could be made 1 index out of the `2 emphasized`?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote

\begin{document}
    
A sentence with words 
and emph index.\index{emph Words@\emph{emph Words}}

Some other words with pagenote 
and emph index.\pagenote{A pagenote with emph words.\index{emph Words@\emph{emph Words}}}

Further words and ordinary index.\index{Words}

Further words with pagenote 
and ordinary index.\pagenote{Further pagenote with ordinary index\index{Words}}

\printnotes

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I still searched for solution, but could not find one. How could this be resolved?

Comment: (1) Use `\index{emph Words@\emph  {emph Words}}`. Note there are *two* additional spaces there. (2) Use `xindy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be observed in the `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{emph Words@\emph{emph Words}}{1}
\indexentry{Words}{1}
\indexentry{emph Words@\emph  {emph Words}}{2}
\indexentry{Words}{2}
```

When `\emph` is used inside the `\pagenote` two additional spaces are inserted afterwards. TeX takes no notice of these because they follow a control sequence immediately, but `makeindex` is more particular. It regards the two entries as distinct.

The easiest and possibly most satisfactory approach is to switch indexing programmes and use `texindy` rather than `makeindex`. All this requires is an option to `\makeindex` (or you can specify when loading `imakeidx`) such as

```
\makeindex[program=xindy]
```

Then you need to run

```
texindy <basename-of-file>.idx
```

If you want split indices or something like that, you may find it easier to run with shell-escape. (`imakeidx`'s documentation says you have to do this just to use the `xindy` option, but that's not true.)

[image: index with texindy]

The quickest, if extremely kludgey, alternative solution is to add two spaces after `\emph` when not inside a `\pagenote`.

```
A sentence with words 
and emph index.\index{emph Words@\emph  {emph Words}}

Some other words with pagenote 
and emph index.\pagenote{A pagenote with emph words.\index{emph Words@\emph{emph Words}}}
```

[image: output from makeindex with manual anti-normalisation of spaces]

A third option would be to track down and address the source of the erroneous spaces or to automate some kind of intervention to ensure the `.idx` file is written one way or the other (either by normalising the input inside the `\pagenote` or by anti-normalising the input elsewhere - or perhaps it is the other way around).

A fourth would be to post-process the `.idx` file before having `makeindex` post-post-process it.

A fifth would be to write a new indexing tool for the twenty-first century ;).

Comment: Thank you so much for your expertise. In my MWE I added `\makeindex[program=xindy]` and this solved the problem. And I did `not` add two spaces! This seems the most elegant of functional way to get the indexes right. Thank you.

Comment: @Thomkrates It isn't a straight substitute in all cases but, where it can work as a drop-in replacement, it is definitely the best option I'm aware of. `makeindex`'s space-thing is a complete pain.

Comment: Ok, I will work on my 440 pages book with 15 pages general index. If I will detect some further problem with this kind of error I will surely come back and ask for support. All the best.